# UINavigationBar back button with pattern image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I need to create a navBar back button in accordance to the designer's plan. The back button has a pattern image and stitched leather on the perimeter.

Here it is:

[image]

My question is it possible to create this without a great amount of hassle and headache? Or if it's possible at all, since the back button has varying width?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Alright, with the help of PartiallyFinite turns out this is very easy. If you set the UIEdgeInsets correctly it will keep the left side fixed, the right side fixed, and then duplicate the middle of the image considering the back button's width.

This is the image I used for my back Button:

[image]

And these are my inset settings. You can try them yourself:

```
backButtonImage = [backButtonImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 17, 5, 12)];
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: create custom UIBarButtonItem

Comment: check out my code helpful to you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to provide a **stretchable image** for the button, so it knows how to display it correctly:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 6)]
```

You don't need to do anything special to the image itself, but you do need to specify appropriate **edge insets** for the resizable image to indicate the area around the edges of the image that should not be stretched, as shown above (the example shows an inset of 15 pixels from the left and 6 from the right). This area should cover the arrow head, and the curved right edge, so that the middle area can be stretched out as needed. [Read the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a) for more information on this method.

**UPDATE:** By default, the resizable area of the image will be tiled to the new size, however if you want to have it stretch instead, you can use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` and pass `UIImageResizingModeStretch` to achieve that behaviour. For your case obviously tiling is better as it preserves the stitching, but for some background images stretching is a better solution. Just putting this here to help anyone who sees this in the future.

Once you have the stretchable image, you can change the appearance your back button using this code:

```
[myBackButtonItem setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Alternatively, you can set this custom appearance for **all** back buttons in your app using this code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Run this when your app launches, and it will affect all back buttons in your app.

Note that, contrary to what some of the other answers suggest, **you will not need to manually create any back buttons**. If you create a `UINavigationController` and use it in the recommended way (read about that [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), a navigation bar and back button **will be created for you** as you push view controllers using `pushViewController:animated:`. If you use the global `UIAppearance` code snippet to apply the custom button style, it will automatically be applied to all the back buttons that you have.

You can read more about `setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` [in the official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackButtonBackgroundImage%3aforState%3abarMetrics%3a).

There are also numerous tutorials available online for a more in-depth explanation of how this works and how to do it, here are a few good ones:

- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/24/using-appearance-proxy-to-style-apps.html
- http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own BarButtonItem. You can't set image for system back button.

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonWithYourImage] autorelease];
```

Comment: That's not a very good solution when this can easily be done with appearance APIs.

Comment: May be :) But as I understand, appearance influences for all barButton items in the app. I think where are situations when this behavior is undesirable :)

Comment: You can set the appearance for a single button using the `setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` method, and that doesn't require making a custom view button.

Comment: Is there any method for iOS 4?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but very few developers bother supporting iOS 4 these days, since [most people have upgraded to at least iOS 5](http://chitika.com/ios-version-distribution), and the majority of people on iOS 4 are only using it because they have very old devices or are jailbroken, so this isn't a significant sector that's worth supporting or mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can  create your own UIBarButtonItem and set it as the leftButtonItem on the navigation bar on the current view controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(yourFunction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my Appdelegate.m to customize button. ("buttonBack" is the name of your image). Hope it may help you

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
UIImage *barButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonBack"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your own back button.. and set that image to back button.

```
UIBarButtonItem * btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(changed)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btn;

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename"]];


-(void)changed
{


    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];

}
```

try this one really helpful to you...

Comment: If a navigation controller is used, back buttons will be created automatically. You do not need to create and assign them to the navigation bar manually.